# Bootstrap Affix - How to use jquery to make boostrap affix?

Tags: jquery

i have a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/okiewardoyo/twkthn44/2/

That fiddle works perfect. bootstrap affix work by using data-offset-top and data-offset-bottom.
My quenstion is, what about if my header and my footer are dynamic. The height of this both are always change on each page.

For now, i use manual height for affix.

```
data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" data-offset-bottom="600"
```

how to use jquery to count my header height and my footer height, and how to implement it to make affix work? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for affix I dynamically set it this way

```
$('#sidebar-affix').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('.navbar').height(),
        bottom: function () {
          return (this.bottom = $('.footer-section').outerHeight(true) + 50)
        }
      }
});
```

**************UPDATE**************

After looking at your fiddle try these changes

javascript

```
$('#nav1').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('header').height(),
        bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = $('footer').outerHeight(true) + 50)
        }
    }
});
```

html (remove `data-spy="affix"`)

```
<ul id="nav1" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="#">Section One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Section Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Section Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
@media (min-width: 979px) {
    #nav1.affix-bottom {
        position: relative;
        margin-top:25px;
    }

    #nav1.affix-top {
        position: static;
        margin-top:25px;
    }

    #nav1.affix {
        position: fixed;
        top:25px;
    }
}

#nav1.affix-top{
    position:static;
}

#nav1.affix-bottom {
    position: relative 
}
```

The `@media` is not necessary, but you get the idea.

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twkthn44/5/)

Comment: I have tried your code, but doesn't work on my case. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/okiewardoyo/twkthn44/3/